# NextJs Nested Layout In Pages Dir

Tags: next.js

I am using Next.js to build my website, but I encountered a problem with nested layouts. Specifically, the layout inside a nested folder doesn't seem to work.

Here's how my current directory structure looks:

```
src /
  components /
    ...
  context /
    ...
  pages /
    - _app.tsx
    - index.tsx
    auth / 
      - layout.tsx
      login / 
        - index.tsx
      register / 
        - index.tsx
```

layout.tsx code

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

interface LayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {  
  return (
    <>
        <h1>Test Layout</h1>
        {children}
    </>
  )
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend utilizing the Next.js 14 `app router` as it's the recommended approach. Begin by creating an `/app` directory within your `/src` folder. Inside this directory, create two files: `page.tsx` and `layout.tsx`. You can then paste your code into these files.

The Next.js 14 app router offers a structured way to organize your application by separating pages and layout components within the `/app` directory. This structure enhances readability and maintainability as your project grows. By adhering to this recommended approach, you can leverage the advantages of Next.js's latest features and maintain a clean project structure.

This setup with the `/app` directory, `page.tsx`, and `layout.tsx` files provides a solid foundation for building your Next.js application, making it easier to manage and scale as your project evolves.

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation

Comment: I was looking into this approach in the beginning, but I wanted to use nextauthjs which does not seem to enable the "getServerSideProps" in the app router?